# Get Access Token expiry using passport-oauth2

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js, passport-facebook

How do we get the **expiry time** of the access token when using **passport-oauth2**? I was able to get the access token and refresh token values only. I tried multiple providers like facebook, box.

Answer (score -1):

You cant get it directly, but check the official SDK doc to learn more about facbook sessions expiration. For example long life session (60 days).
[Facebook login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension)